# Responsive Background Image (animated fade loop) that will span full height of page content?

Tags: css, animation, background, responsive, viewport

**ITERATION 1 :**

I've got a quite pleasant animation going on in the background. It is responsive, filling the viewport on the fly (you can resize the window and it adjusts). However, if the content on the page exceeds the height of the viewport, I get a scrollbar (as expected); but when I scroll down I see the black background of the site (and not the background image).

If you go to the page and resize your window so that the viewport is shorter than the content, then scroll, you'll see what I mean : https://www.vortex42studios.com

Is it not possible to have the background image scale to the height of the page OR the viewport height, whichever of the two happens to be the longest in px at any given moment?

IE : If the page content is 1000px and the viewport is 700px, then the background spans 1000px in height.

And, if the page content is 500px, and the viewport is 750px, then the background image spans to the 750px height of the viewport.

So that it looks good both when there are, and are not scrollbars? Preferably responsively, as it is now, where you can resize the window and the background image adjusts accordingly on the fly. I would very much like to keep this to a CSS-only solution if at all possible.

Surely this is possible. I'm obviously missing something, but can't figure it out. Help would be massively appreciated.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

* {
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, "serif";
  font-size: 3vw;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {}

.content {
  font-size: 2vw;
  flex: 1;
}

.footer {}

plateBG {
  animation-name: imageAnimation;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 25s;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: visible;
}

plateBG:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG01_1080P.JPG);
}

plateBG:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
  background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG02_1080P.JPG);
}

plateBG:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 10s;
  background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG03_1080P.JPG);
}

plateBG:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 15s;
  background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG04_1080P.JPG);
}

plateBG:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 20s;
  background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG05_1080P.JPG);
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


}
```

```html
<plateBG></plateBG>
<plateBG></plateBG>
<plateBG></plateBG>
<plateBG></plateBG>
<plateBG></plateBG>

<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="header">
    <p>vortex42studios</p>
    <p>Film and Animation Effects Studios</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <p>This is content</p>
    <p>This is content</p>
    <p>This is content</p>
    <p>This is content</p>
    <p>This is content</p>
    <p>This is content</p>
    <p>This is content</p>
    <p>This is content</p>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <p>Relaunching soon</p>
    <p>Facilities in Scotland and Denmark</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ITERATION 2 :**

I couldn't make any of the methods found on SO to force an absolute div to take on the height of its parent (when that element's height is auto) work.

So, turning to putting the images as backgrounds on the the body itself, using a pseudo before element for images fading in and after for fading out it works. Body height is set to auto, but with `min-height: 100vh`.

**BUT**, it takes a lot of GPU, even more than (current at time of writing this) https://www.vortex42studios.com, so let's hope someone can come up with something better. Otherwise we are in danger of draining the user's mobile battery or their laptop scorching their knees.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
    body {
      height: auto;
      min-height: 100vh;
      width: auto;
      overflow: visible;
      position: relative;
    }
    body::before, body::after {
        display: inline-block;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: relative;
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        animation: none 25s infinite ease;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100vh;
        z-index: -1;
        overflow: visible;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
    }
    body::before {
      animation-name: fadein;
    }
    body::after {
        animation-name: fadeout;
    }
    @keyframes fadein {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
        background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG01_1080P.JPG);
      }
      20% {
        opacity: 1;
        background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG01_1080P.JPG);
        }
      20.001% {
        opacity: 0;
        background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG02_1080P.JPG);
        }
      40% {
        opacity: 1;
        background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG02_1080P.JPG);
        }
      40.001% {
        opacity: 0;
        background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG03_1080P.JPG);
        }
      60% {
        opacity: 1;
        background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG03_1080P.JPG);
        }
      60.001% {
        opacity: 0;
        background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG04_1080P.JPG);
        }
      80% {
        opacity: 1;
        background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG04_1080P.JPG);
      }
      80.001% {
        opacity: 0;
        background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG05_1080P.JPG);
        }  
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG05_1080P.JPG);
        }
    }
    @keyframes fadeout {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
        background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG05_1080P.JPG);
      }
      20% {
        opacity: 0;
        background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG05_1080P.JPG);
        }
      20.001% {
        opacity: 1;
        background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG01_1080P.JPG);
        }
      40% {
        opacity: 0;
        background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG01_1080P.JPG);
        }
      40.001% {
        opacity: 1;
        background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG02_1080P.JPG);
        }
      60% {
        opacity: 0;
        background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG02_1080P.JPG);
        }
      60.001% {
        opacity: 1;
        background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG03_1080P.JPG);
        }
      80% {
        opacity: 0;
        background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG03_1080P.JPG);
      }
      80.001% {
        opacity: 1;
        background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG04_1080P.JPG);
        }  
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
        background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG04_1080P.JPG);
        }
    }
    .wrap {
      height: auto;
      width: 100%;;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br></div>
```

Comment: That is fantastic! Great solution! Thank you so much!

And, I've managed to make a huge improvement in terms of efficiency/resources too. Check out my follow up answer.

Answer (score 1):

**ITERATION 3 :**

Following up on *A Haworth's* brilliant solution (*Iteration 2 above*) of using the "before" and "after" pseudo layers on the body tag to ensure the background image is always visible, even when the content of the page exceeds the length of the viewport, here is a further improvement that greatly reduces the GPU resource hogging.

In A Hawthorn's example he has image#2 fading in at the same time as image#1 is fading out. This does use a lot of resources. But, it also looks less pleasing because with both images fading at the same time, the background-color shows through.

Instead, in this version, the lower "before" layer simply shows a slideshow of the images at full opacity. And, the fade-in animations only happen on the upper "after" layer. The "before" layer has an animation-delay of 5 seconds so that the image that previously faded in is underneath the next image that fades in.

It looks very pleasing, and is considerably less resource intensive.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
    body {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000000;
}
body::before, body::after {
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: visible;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

/*ANIMATIONS - LOWER : HOLDS DELAYED 5 SECONDS*/
body::before {
    animation: lowerHold 25s ease-in 5s infinite none;
}       
@keyframes lowerHold {
    0%, 100%        { opacity : 1;  }
    0%, 20%         { background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG01_1080P.JPG); }
    20.001%, 40%    { background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG02_1080P.JPG); }
    40.001%, 60%    { background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG03_1080P.JPG); }
    60.001%, 80%    { background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG04_1080P.JPG); }
    80.001%, 100%   { background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG05_1080P.JPG); }
}

/*ANIMATIONS - UPPER : FADES*/      
body::after {
    animation: upperFadeIn 25s ease-in 0s infinite none;
}
@keyframes upperFadeIn {
    /*FADE : IMAGE 01*/
    0%, 20%     { background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG01_1080P.JPG); }
    0%          { opacity: 0;   }
    10%         { opacity: 1;   }
    20%         { opacity: 1;   }
    /*FADE : IMAGE 02*/
    20.001%,40% { background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG02_1080P.JPG); }
    20.001%     { opacity: 0;   }
    30%         { opacity: 1;   }
    40%         { opacity: 1;   }
    /*FADE : IMAGE 03*/
    40.001%,60% { background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG03_1080P.JPG); }
    40.001%     { opacity: 0;   }
    50%         { opacity: 1;   }
    60%         { opacity: 1;   }
    /*FADE : IMAGE 04*/
    60.001%,80% { background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG04_1080P.JPG); }
    60.001%     { opacity: 0;   }
    70%         { opacity: 1;   }
    80%         { opacity: 1;   }
    /*FADE : IMAGE 05*/
    80.001%,100%{ background-image: url(https://www.vortex42studios.com/source/img/BG05_1080P.JPG); }
    80.001%     { opacity: 0;   }
    90%         { opacity: 1;   }
    100%        { opacity: 1;   }
}

.wrap {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br></div>
```

Comment: Excellent addition - wish I'd thought of it. The GPU usage now cycles between 0 and 60% instead of being stuck at around 70% constantly last time I looked.

Comment: I couldn't have got to that without your introduction of pseudos. So, thank you again!

Comment: Hi again, @AHaworth - If you're interested, I've added another iteration, this time integrating PHP to the CSS in order to trawl a specified directory, and automatically build an array of image filenames, which then uses for loops to populate the CSS animation details, adjusting for however many images it finds, all on the fly. So, adding or removing image files to that directory (as many or few as you like - each with any naming convention at all) will be instantly reflected on your site. Check out Iteration 4 below. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

**ITERATION 4 :**

Here's one last iteration to complete this wee project.

This time, I'm using PHP to populate the CSS such that the background images and animations are built on the fly from the contents of the specified directory.

This "final" iteration includes all of the benefits of the previous one, including *A Haworth's* brilliant use of "before" and "after" pseudos on the body tag, to correctly scale the background image animations to the page even when the page contents exceed the height of the viewing port. And, also it includes the same resource saving approach I put together in the previous iteration.

Unfortunately, because StackOverflow doesn't allow PHP in code snippets, you can't run it here to see this working. But, I'm including the code below, and will explain here what it is doing...

The PHP code, within the CSS, trawls the specified directory `$imgDir` for only image files of the specified formats `jpeg|jpg|png|gif`, regardless of whether the file extension is upper or lower case, and builds an array `$images` of their filenames. It then uses `shuffle($images)` so that every time the page loads, the images appear in a different order.

Based on the number of filenames in the array `$imgNum = count($images)` and the amount of time each image should be displayed for (which is set to `5` seconds in the variable `$imgDur`), the PHP then determines the overall duration of the animations `$aniDur = $imgNum * $imgDur`. And, then calculates what percentage segment `$aniSeg` (ie `10` percent) of the total animation (ie `100` percent) will be occupied by each of the images, and also uses `number_format()` to give `$aniSeg` two decimal places (ie `10.00` percent - which is important later for accurate keyframe timings).

We now start on the lower "before" layer slideshow animation, as follows...

The animation `lowerHold` is declared using `$aniDur` for the `animation-duration` attribute, and `$imgDur` for the `$animation-delay` attribute. This slideshow animation is delayed 5 seconds, so that the current image remains visible on this lower layer, while next image is fading in on the upper "after" layer animation.

Next, the keyframes for the `lowerHold` animation are set.

First, the opacity is set to `1`, throughout the animation, using `0.001%, 100% { opacity : 1;  }`. A new variable `$pos` for "position" is set to `0 - $aniSeg`, then it is given two decimal places using `number_format()`. The `$pos` variable can then be used to set keyframe timings in percentages (it is set to a negative number here, to allow for clean incrementation in the coming loop through the array).

Then, a `for(){ ... }` loop is used, based on the incremental variable `$i` (initially set to `0`) as compared to the `$imgNum` variable telling how many filenames there are in the array.

The for loop starts by incrementing `$pos` by adding `$aniSeg` onto it. The for loop then proceeds with a single `echo` command which uses `$pos . "1%"` for the start point percentage timing (the "1" here is a concatenated 3rd decimal place required for precise keyframe timing on start points, and the required percent sign), and `$pos + $aniSeg . "%"` for the end point percentage timing, and `$imgDir . $images[$i]`, for the location of the current image (ie `/images/image001.jpg`). Using these variables the for loop builds a list of keyframe animation commands; in this particular example, one for each image in the `images` array.

We then do a similar process for the upper "after" layer fade-in animation, as follows...

The animation `upperFadeIn` is declared using `$aniDur` for the `animation-duration` attribute, and `$imgDur - $imgDur` for the `$animation-delay` attribute. Subtracting `$imgDur` from itself results in `0`, which means this animation plays immediately (unlike the previous one which is delayed 5 seconds), so that each image fades in on top of the previous image currently showing on the lower "before" layer slideshow animation.

Next, the keyframes for the `upperFadeIn` animation are set.

The previously used `$pos` variable for "position" is reset back to `0 - $aniSeg`, and given two decimal places using `number_format()`, in preparation for setting the keyframe timings in percentages (again - it is set to a negative number here, to allow for clean incrementation in the coming loop through the array).

Then, a `for(){ ... }` loop is used, based on the incremental variable `$i` (initially set to `0`) as compared to the `$imgNum` variable telling how many filenames there are in the array.

The for loop starts by incrementing `$pos` by adding `$aniSeg` onto it. The for loop then proceeds with five `echo` commands which use a number of calculations involving the variables `$pos` and `$aniSeg` to obtain the start point, and end point, percentage timings for the various steps in the animation (as in the previous for loop above, the start points are concatenated with `1%` which is a 3rd decimal place required for precise keyframe timing on start points, and the required percent sign - The end points are concatenated simply with `%`)...

1. The 1st `echo` is simply a commented-out label describing what is
   happening.
2. The 2nd `echo` loads in the current image using the
   locator variables `$imgDir . $images[$i]` just as seen in
   the previous animation.
3. The 3rd `echo` sets the start point keyframe
   for opacity to `0`.
4. The 4th `echo` sets the mid point keyframe for
   opacity to `1`.
5. The 5th `echo` sets the end point keyframe for
   opacity also to `1`.

The for loop repeats this series of keyframe animation commands for each image in the `images` array.

Note, that there is a variable `$new` containing `\n` and some whitespace, which is used throughout the commands in the for loops, simply to tidy up the code.

And, that is the lot.

So, with this code, you can set these three variables...

1. Set `$imgDur` to the number of seconds to display each image (ie
   `5`).
2. Set `$imgDir` to the directory containing background images (ie `/images/`).
3. Set `$imgExt` to the file types you want to trawl for (ie `jpeg|jpg|png|gif`).

...Then the code will automatically build an array of the filenames of images found in the specified directory `$imgDir`, shuffle them, and set the overall animation duration based on how long you want the images to display for `$imgDur`, and also build all of the individual keyframe timings for both animations on the fly, and display the background animations, all based on the image files found in the directory.

This way, you can add as many image files to that directory as you like, delete some, replace some, swap them around, or whatever you like, no matter what the filenames are, and the results will automatically update on your site, all without having to touch the code again.

You could even have buttons on your site that change the value of `$imgDir` so that each button loads background images from a different directory. Very handy all round.

Here is the code! Enjoy!

**CSS with PHP elements throughout :**
*to integrate this in your site either stick it in `<style></style>` tags in the `<head>` of a `.php` file, or include it as a separate CSS file that has the extension `.php`*.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000000;
}
body::before, body::after {
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: visible;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

<?php       
    //REQUIRED VARS
    $imgDur = 5;                                //SET DISPLAY TIME FOR EACH IMAGE IN SECONDS
    $imgDir = "/source/img/";                   //SET DIRECTORY TO TRAWL FOR IMAGES
    $imgExt = "jpeg|jpg|png|gif";               //SET THE IMAGE EXTENSIONS YOU ARE TRAWLING FOR
    $imgPth = getcwd() . $imgDir;               //PATH TO IMAGE DIRECTORY (NOT INCLUDING $webUrl !!!)

    //CREATE ARRAY OF ALL IMAGES IN DIRECTORY THEN SHUFFLE ORDER
    $images = preg_grep("~\.(" . $imgExt . ")$~i", array_values(preg_grep("/^([^.])/", scandir($imgPth))));
    shuffle($images);

    //FURTHER REQUIRED VARS
    $imgNum = count($images);                                   //NUMBER OF IMAGES IN ARRAY
    $aniDur = $imgNum * $imgDur;                                //TOTAL ANIMATION DURATION IN SECONDS 
    $aniSeg = number_format((float)100 / $imgNum, 2, '.', '');  //PERCENTAGE OF ANIMATION PER IMAGE
    $new = "\n          "; //NEW LINE + WHITESPACE FOR USE CLEANING UP FOR LOOPS
?>

/*ANIMATIONS - LOWER : HOLDS DELAYED 5 SECONDS*/
body::before {
    animation: lowerHold <?php echo $aniDur . "s" ?> ease-in <?php echo $imgDur . "s" ?> infinite none;
}
@keyframes lowerHold {
    0.001%, 100% { opacity : 1; } 
    <?php
        $pos = 0 - $aniSeg;
        $i = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $imgNum; $i++) {
        $pos += $aniSeg;
        $pos = number_format((float)$pos, 2, '.', '');
        echo $new . $pos . "1%, " . ($pos+$aniSeg) . "% { background-image: url(" . $imgDir . $images[$i] . ");}";
        }
    ?>

}

/*ANIMATIONS - UPPER : FADES*/      
body::after {
    animation: upperFadeIn <?php echo $aniDur . "s" ?> ease-in <?php echo $imgDur - $imgDur . "s" ?> infinite none;
}
@keyframes upperFadeIn {
    <?php
        $pos = 0 - $aniSeg;
        $i = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $imgNum; $i++) {
            $pos += $aniSeg;
            $pos = number_format((float)$pos, 2, '.', '');
            echo $new . "/*FADE : IMAGE " . ($i + 1) . "*/";
            echo $new . $pos . "1%, " . ($pos + $aniSeg) . "% { background-image: url(" . $imgDir . $images[$i] . ");}";
            echo $new . $pos . "1% { opacity: 0; }";
            echo $new . ($pos + ($aniSeg / 2)) . "% { opacity: 1; }";
            echo $new . ($pos + $aniSeg) . "% { opacity: 1; }";
        }
    ?>

}

.wrap {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br></div>
```